# Pubnub invalid timestamp

Tags: pubnub, ntp

I always get this from my console, whenever I use PAM and grant.

```
Object {message: "Invalid Timestamp"}
```

I already setup NTP to my ubuntu server but still nothing change.

my pubnub grant is here:

```
 pubnub.grant({
  channel  : channel,
  callback : function (m) { console.log("grant success: ", m); },
  error    : function (m) { console.log("grant error: ", m); },
  ttl      : 5, // Minutes
  read     : true,
  write    : false,
  auth_key : 'auth_key_here'
 });
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The NTP should have fixed this. Double sure that this is installed/configured correctly?
Can you send full code/script zipped to [PubNub Support](http://www.pubnub.com/support)?

Comment: Also, are you initializing pubnub instance with you secret-key?

Comment: Still having issues or did you resolve?

Comment: Hi craig yup we still have this issue, and since we are doing some rush work we decided to create a temporary features using socket.io.. Will try to fix this after this sprint. Thanks for the quick support men!

Comment: OK, but the solution for the Invalid Timestamp should be super simple. Just send details to support@pubnub.com and we'll dig in.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the given steps to setup NTP server for the pubnub.

Step 1 Installation NTP

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Step 2 Edit ntp.conf

```
Replace these four with pubnub server 



server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 
    server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 
    server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 
    server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 

    to

    server 0.pubsub.pubnub.com
    server 1.pubsub.pubnub.com
    server 2.pubsub.pubnub.com
    server 3.pubsub.pubnub.com
```

Step 3 Restart NTP Service

```
$ sudo service ntp restart
```